# Для чего нужны параметры указателю на функцию?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Заранее извиняюсь за столь тупой вопрос, но для чего мы пишем список параметров, когда объявляем указатель на функцию. Допустим у нас есть функция:

```
int foo(int i)
{  return i; }
```

При объявлении указателя мы напишем:

```
int (*smth)(int) = foo;
```

При чем мы можем даже не указывать имя параметра. Почему бы тогда вообще не оставить эти скобки пустыми? Складывается ощущение, что эти параметры бесполезны (я сердечно верю, что это не так). Или все так это для чего то нужно?

Comment: Эм.. А ты вызвать потом это пробовал?

Comment: Да просто при вызове вы не сможете передать ей параметр - компилятор будет уверен, что это функция - **как вы сами написали** - без параметра. Правда, он и указатель без насильственного приведения не присвоит... С++ - язык строго типизированный... Кстати, вас никогда не удивляло, что возвращаемый тип тоже указывается без имени? :) А если вы возразите, что это имя - имя функции, то я отвечу, что и для параметров это имя функции, вернее, ее *сигнатура*...

Comment: В С++ описание типов параметров в прототипе функции обязательно. Пустые скобки означают, что параметров нет. В Си пустые скобки означают, что функция принимает любой список параметров (в т.ч. вызов без параметров).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, система типов в С++ различает типы функций таким образом:

тип возвращаемого значения и список типов аргументов образуют тип функции.

В этом смысле, например, все функции, "принимающие пару интов и возвращающие инт" являются функциями одного типа.

именно поэтому можно написать версию "калькулятора", где внутрь некой функции передаётся пара аргументов и функция, "что то делающая с ними", в качестве параметра.

Этот параметр (указатель на функцию) будет преобразован обратно в вызов функции.

Количество аргументов и их типы нужны для того, чтобы понимать, сколько памяти выделить на стеке при вызове функции.

Вообще, еще это похоже на систему "делегатов" в C#. И там есть invocation list, куда можно добавлять функции одного типа, для того, чтобы вызвать их "все вместе" на одном и том же наборе аргументов.

Примечание 1. Как Вы знаете, в С++ есть возможность написать очень похожие функции:

```
    int add (int x, int y);
    int add (int& x, int& y);
    int add (const int& x, const int& y);
    int add (const int& x, const int& y) const;
```

и всё это будут разные типы функций.

**'Правила' получения указателя на функцию.**

Расммотрим два примера

Пример с типом int

```
    int x = 42;   // переменная типа int
    int* px = &x; // указатель на такую переменную
```

Пример с функцией

```
    int summ(const int& x, const int & y);         // сигнатура функции
    int (*)(const int&, const int&) pf = &summ;    // указатель на функцию
```

Как получить "тип функции":

Берем тип возвращаемого значения. К нему приписываем (в скобках!) звездочку. потом пишем еще одни скобки. А вот если кол-во аргументов функции >0, то нужно ТИПЫ этих аргументов перечислить вот в этих последних скобках через запятую.

Пример: int f_for_return_int();
Её тип: int (*)();

Если Вы сомневааетесь и хотите, чтобы компилятор Вам подсказал:
Очень просто - нужно намерено сделать ошибку, например:

```
    auto pf = &f_for_return_int;
    auto r = pf/0;                 // в этой строке возникнет ошибка error: invalid operands of types 'int (*)()' and 'int'...
```

Если у Вас еще есть вопросы -не стесняйтесь их задать в комментариях.

Comment: Нет, не похоже это на с#, указатель на функцию, это адрес по которому ее может вызвать программа, при помощи  инструкции `call`, в то время как в с#, это целый объект класса.

Comment: указатель на функцию может быть как просто адрес этой функции, так и целая структура, в  некоторых случаях достигающая размера в три указателя (но это не обычная функция, а функция член класса, при этом сам класс хитровиртуальный)

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ, только мне единственное непонятно - что значит "функции одного типа" или "тип (не тот который она возвращает) функции"? Просто ни разу не слышал это термин.

Comment: Я сейчас постараюсь дополнить ответ, чтобы соблюсти чистоту речи и пояснить этот термин. Как дополню - напишу

Answer (score 1):

В С++ допускается перегрузка функций. Т.е. возможно описать две функции с одинаковым именем. В этом случае, компилятор будет различать вызов по типу аргументов функции (тип возвращаемого значения не важен).

Пример:

```
int foo(int x);
int foo(int &x);
```

- это две разные функции.

Соответственно, и указатели на них должны быть объявлены по разному:

```
int (*fooPtr)(int) = foo;
int (*fooPtr)(&int) = foo;
```